# Check if username exists before hitting the submit button using PHP CodeIgniter and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to check if a username exists even before hitting the submit button using CodeIgniter. Here is the Javascript in my view.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--\
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#username').keyup(username_check);
});

function username_check(){  
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == "" || username.length < 4){
$('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
$('#tick').hide();
}else{

jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "addpatient/insert",
   data: 'username='+ username,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
if(response == 1){
    $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
    $('#tick').hide();
    $('#cross').fadeIn();
    }else{
    $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
    $('#cross').hide();
    $('#tick').fadeIn();
         }

}
});
}



}

</script>
```

Here is a part of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="addpatient/insert">
        <table id='addpatient'>
            <tr>    
                <td width=100> Username:
                <td width=150>  <input type='text' id='username' name='username'>
            </tr> .....
```

Here is a part of the the controller (function `insert`)

```
$patient['username'] = strtolower($this->input->post('username'));
$response = $this->user->check_username($patient['username']);
```

Here is a function in the model:

```
function check_username_availability($username){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $num = $query->num_rows();

    return $num;

 }
```

The result is always valid whenever I try it even though such username already exists in the database. I think my problem is in the `type: "POST"` of the javascript. And how could it get the number of rows fetched (fetched in the `model`) to the javascript? I just pattered my code [here](http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-mysql-username-availability-checker/). Please help me make this work. I'm new in using CodeIgniter framework. Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#username').keyup(username_check);
});

function username_check(){  
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == "" || username.length < 4){
$('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
$('#tick').hide();
}else{

var url = 'addpatient/insert';
var data = {username:'username'};
$.post(url, data, function(result){
   console.log(result);
  function(response){
if(response == 1){
    $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
    $('#tick').hide();
    $('#cross').fadeIn();
    }else{
    $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
    $('#cross').hide();
    $('#tick').fadeIn();
         }

}
}
});
}



}
```

Comment: Is the missing `$` in `return num;` of your `function check_username_availability($username){}` a typo? -> `return $num;`?

Comment: Yes it's just a typo. Even with the `$`, the result is always valid.

Comment: please use $this->db->escape($username) there. CI has built in methods for sanitizing input

Comment: success: function(response) here response have value only if you echo something on your controller. did you echo anything there ?

Comment: Within this section `success: function(response){}` please add `console.log(response);` like this `success: function(response){console.log(response);}` and check your Console window to see if the result is what you need.

Comment: Also, what are you doing with `$response = $this->user->check_username($patient['username']);`? Is this getting stright echo'ed or are you doing an `echo json_encode($response);`?

Comment: @KaiQing You mean like this `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '". $this->db->escape($username) ."'"`? Tried it but it still has the same error.

@Akhil5 I replaced the `return $num` with `echo $num` and it still doesn't work properly.

@MonkeyZeus What do you mean by Console? I'm sorry I only run my code at localhost using xampp. Tried putting the `console.log(respose)` though.

Comment: @FionnlaghEndika What browser are you using? Although it honestly shouldn't matter unless it is IE7 or lower. Press F12 and look for a "console" tab

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I added `echo json_encode($response);` after `$response = ....` and now all username I type in the textfield is invalid. I'm using Firefox and I tried pressing the F12 button but no other window appeared.

Comment: I didn't mean this was an answer to your problem. I was just pointing out that you were accepting raw user input without sanitizing it. That's a security hole is all. And yes, your sample usage of it is correct, though you do not need the single quotes. escape adds them automatically

Comment: @FionnlaghEndika Sorry I forgot F12 only works if you have FireBug installed for FireFox. Try doing the combination `Ctrl + Shift + k` or if you use IE or Chrome then F12 should work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your php code returns the correct value...
Trim your result in your success callback or return json.

```
if($.trim(response) == 1)
```

Comment: What do you do if by mistake there's two username with the same name ? Better be safe and use `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function check_username_availability($username){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $num = $query->num_rows();

    echo $num; //echo the value instead return

 }
```

Comment: His/her AJAX is calling the `insert()` function so his `insert()` function should be the one echo'ing `$result`

Answer (score 0):

I think your ajax call is the problem. The data that you are posting should be an object. Try doing it in jquery. its easier:

```
var url = 'addpatient/insert';
var data = {username:'username'};
$.post(url, data, function(result){
   console.log(result);
   ..your success function..
});
```

Comment: Also, where in your controller are you calling your model and how? can you please post the code?

Comment: I called the model at the very first part of the controller by `$this->load->model('user', '', TRUE);` (user is the model). Other lines of codes in the controller are just "post"-ing the values in the form and adding those in the database.

Comment: is this a typo? $response = $this->user->check_username($patient['username']);    It should be the name of your function: check_username_AVAILABILTY

Comment: I'm sorry for that. And sir, I don't get your answer. Please see edit for my trial.

Comment: oh sorry. Ill ask better. In your controller you are calling your model to get the $response. You are calling your model by the function name 'check_username', but in your Model code I see the following function: 'function check_username_availability()'. It seems that you are trying to call this function but it is not spelled correctly. it seems that in your controller you are missing the word 'availability'

Comment: I happen to have that function in the model that returns 0 or 1. Now I modified it to`check_username_availability` and still gets the same error-- username is valid all the time.

Comment: I see that you posted your edited version. Nice. what do you get in your console after doing the change to the $.post ?

Comment: for the console try hitting F12. Then click on CONSOLE on the menu. you should see the results there

Comment: It doesn't check the textfield anymore. It is neither valid or invalid. I tried it (f12) but there is no menu or something.

Comment: ok great. try installing the FIREBUG plugin. it seems that you dont have it. https://getfirebug.com/